# how to create a custom home page based on user profile

Tags: oauth, oauth2

I wish to create different custom home pages for users based on their profile, not the normal **salesforce login** page. Is it possible to create? Provide your thoughts.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You seem to be referencing two different pages.  Are you talking about the home page, ie- after they login, or the SF login page?

Comment: Instead of salesforce login i want to create a custom login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to customize your SF login page currently is not available, but soon will be with the Winter 14 release.  According to the documentation, with the release adminstrators will be able to

```
Customize the look and feel of your login page by adding a background color, logo, and right-frame content.
```

https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf

http://sforcecloud.blogspot.com/p/salesforce-winter14-features.html

So unfortuneatly, its not available at the moment, but in a very short amount of time it will be.  Heres the schedule for the Winter 14 release

http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/

Comment: Is there any idea on how to customize login page for different users in winter 14?